# JSF2 upgrade to existing project

Tags: jsf-2

Im tring to upgrade existing project JSF2.I faced so many problems with combination of SUN RI and myfaces so i eliminated all SUN RI's from classpath now combination of facelets and myfaces is giving problem. I wanted to know if we eliminate facelets and make use of just apache myfaces what should be the taglib namespace?? im getting this error

```
        27 Dec, 2010 7:08:28 PM org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewHandler handleRenderException SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/login.xhtml] 

        java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:57)
         at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:45) 
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:322) 
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:369) 
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:363) 
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.UserTagHandler.apply(UserTagHandler.java:116) 

    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:51) 
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:57) at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:51)
```

Please help me if anyone worked on JSF2 upgrade..

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a JSF 2 / Facelets project using MyFaces 2.0.2. I have only the `myfaces-impl` and `myfaces-api` JARs plus some from Apache Commons in the classpath.

My Facelets namespace declaration is `xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply.I removed jsf-facelets.jar and using myfaces facelets will the above namespace declaration will work?If yes i dont know y im getting attached error.

Comment: @teja: it works for me. As for the error, are you declaring any *other* namespaces that could cause the problem? You might want to use a debugger to find out what exactly it's trying to do when the Exception happens.

Comment: combination of SUN JSF and Apache Myfaces works for you.Probably I need to try some more configurations by adding facelets FaceletViewHandler..etc currently I used org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewHandler viewhandler in my faces-config.xml

Comment: @teja: No. I am using *only* Apache Myfaces, and my faces-config.xml is empty except for some message bundle and converter definitions.